# Resetting scale after transformation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

```
_cardView =[card initCard];

[self.view addSubview:_cardView];

_cardView.transform=CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.1, 0.1);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     _cardView.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                 }];
```

I have a view which I animate to make it seem as if it is expanding from a point (similar to the animation of an app being opened). This view is returned from [card initCard], with card being a custom class, and assigned to _cardView. Using CGAffineTransformScale I first decrease the scale and then animate the increase of the scale. This works perfectly for the first card that is shown. However, when _cardView is set to nil and a new card is assigned to it, the same transformation and animation code produce the wrong animation which makes the view increase in scale before decreasing. I assume that the problem is in making the scale 0.1,0.1 but I have not been able to solve this.

Setting to nil:

```
else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
{
    if(sender.view.center.x>0){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            CGRect rect=[sender.view frame];
            rect.origin.x=([self.view frame].size.width/2)-129.5;
            [sender.view setFrame:rect];
            sender.view.alpha  = 0.8;

        }];
    }else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            _protoypeView.alpha=0.0;
            _protoypeView=nil;
            _cardView=nil;

            [self nextCard];
        }];
    }
}
```

and function nextCard:

```
    -(void)nextCard{
    if(cardNumber>[questionArray count]-1){
        NSLog(@"Out of cards");
    }else{
        QuestionCard *card=[[QuestionCard alloc]init];
        NSArray* array =[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:questionArray[cardNumber]];
        card.questionString=array[3];
        card.whenPosted=array[0];
        card.isAnon=array[2];
        card.user=array[1];
        card.replies=array[4];
        card.profileImg=array[5];
        _cardView =[card initCard];
        [self.view addSubview:_cardView];
        _cardView.alpha=0.0;
        _cardView.transform=CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -1, -1);
        _cardView.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            _cardView.alpha=0.7;
        }];

        UIPanGestureRecognizer * pan1 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanImage:)];
        pan1.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
        [_cardView addGestureRecognizer:pan1];
        yOfView=[_cardView frame].origin.y+([_cardView frame].size.height/2);
        cardNumber++;

    }
}
```

First case of CGAffineTransform (after successful query to Parse database):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
                _protoypeView.alpha=0.0;
            }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                QuestionCard *card=[[QuestionCard alloc]init];
                NSArray* array =[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:questionArray[cardNumber]];
                card.questionString=array[3];
                card.whenPosted=array[0];
                card.isAnon=array[2];
                card.user=array[1];
                card.replies=array[4];
                card.profileImg=array[5];
                _cardView =[card initCard];

                [self.view addSubview:_cardView];

                _cardView.transform=CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.0, 0.0);
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                 animations:^{
                                     _cardView.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                                 }];
                UIPanGestureRecognizer * pan1 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanImage:)];
                pan1.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
                [_cardView addGestureRecognizer:pan1];
                yOfView=[_cardView frame].origin.y+([_cardView frame].size.height/2);
                cardNumber++;

            }];
```

Comment: Show the part how to `nil` out the card and how this part is called again.

Comment: There are many things that need to be changed here; but let's stay focus on your question: where do you place the first block of code? It is not in any of the code you just added.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - [self nextCard] was called in animations, but should be called in completion.